# How to align a background to an image, even with resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I achieve this effect?

The gray image is a background and the blue box is a img.

I am using Bootstrap.

In a large screen looks like this. There are two divs, each spanning 6 columns (out of 12).

[image: Normal size]

When resizing, for example in a mobile device, the text goes below the image.

[image: Resized]

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: please provide code  here or jsfiddle

Comment: Have you tried playing with `background-position` using Bootstrap's `media-queries`? Eq, on a large screen use `center left` and mobile: `top center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this using CSS multiple backgrounds.

Please see this example based on the example found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds) documentation:

```
<div class="multi_bg_example"></div>

.multi_bg_example {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11305/firefox.png), url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11307/bubbles.png), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: 100px 100px, left, right;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), -webkit-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), -ms-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/e79gb1w5/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">IMG goes here</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Text goes here</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I juggled with x, y positioning of the background as Luk Skeuur recommended.

Code in: https://jsfiddle.net/nd1mmdf3/

```
.with-bg {
  background-image: url('bg.jpg');
  background-position: -240px -180px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: So that was your problem? You didn't know how to set the position for the image in the main div? I thought you don't want to use an image in the html or something more special. This is why question should have code.

Comment: The background, not the image